# Why does modifying AUTH_USER_MODEL seem required to subclass AbstractUser?

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-custom-user

After creating a projet, then an app and adding this app to my `INSTALLED_APPS`, I tried to make a custom User class by subclassing `AbstractUser` in my `models.py` :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Then I tried to run `makemigrations` and I got this error :

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'CustomUser.groups'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'CustomUser.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'CustomUser.user_permissions'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'CustomUser.user_permissions'.
main.CustomUser.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'CustomUser.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'CustomUser.groups' or 'User.groups'.
main.CustomUser.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'CustomUser.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'CustomUser.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
```

Adding `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.CustomUser'` (`main` is my app) seems to solve this problem (`makemigrations` succeeds, just like `migrate`), but I don't get why I get this error even if I just define this subclass **without actually using it yet**.

I'd like to understand why this problem occured in first place, and how does adding `AUTH_USER_MODEL` solve it. I don't really understand why it looks like there is a conflict between my `CustomUser` and `auth.User`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Custom User model inherits `AbstractUser` which is a model class of `django.contrib.auth`.

`AbstractUser` defines itself from `AbstractBaseUser` and `PermissionsMixin` models and is thus related with the Group and Permission models via PermissionsMixin class

`PermissionsMixin` defines a `ManyToManyField` relationship to `Permission` and `Groups`(which is further related ManyToMany with the `Permission`) models like:

```
class PermissionsMixin(models.Model):
....

    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        ....
        related_name="user_set",
        related_query_name="user",
    )
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Permission,
        ....
        related_name="user_set",
        related_query_name="user",
    )
```

`PermissionsMixin` defines `related_name="user_set"` with the `Permission` and `Group` models and thus the `AbstractUser` Model has reverse relation to these models.

When you subclass the `AbstractUser`, you defines two models that are having reverse relationship with `Group` and `Permission` with the same `related_name`.

> But You can't have two generic or foreign keys with identical related_names pointing to the same model.
>
> You must always specify a unique reverse name and query name for the field. This would normally cause a problem in abstract base classes, since the fields on this class are included into each of the child classes, with exactly the same values for the attributes.

Therefore you can have only one subclass of a `AbstractUser` in your application.

If you subclass `AbstractUser` then you have to point that child model to AUTH_USER_MODEL, so that your Application points to exactly one instance of a AbstractUser and not two.

Answer (score 1):

Because AbstractUser (or rather the PermissionMixin that it inherits from) defines relations with those other models - ie groups, permissions - and it uses a hard-coded related_name attribute, `user_set`, to avoid confusion if the model is swapped out.

That's fine as long as the class remains abstract, but as soon as you define a concrete subclass then Django will define the reverse relations to that model; now you have two models that use the same value, `user_set`, as the related name from Group.

If you set AUTH_USER_MODEL, then Django no longer defines the standard User class; so you're back to the situation where only one class uses that related_name.